# Co-ordinate math in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm working with Canvas and JS, I have a simple physics sim where a ball is added to the canvas and reacts to gravity, collisions and drag.

Currently it can be fired around by dragging (like an elastic band).

```
function drawSlingshot() {
if (mouse.isDown) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(ball.position.x, ball.position.y);
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

}

Here's my function for drawing a line indicating where the ball will go. It's unfortunately doing the opposite of what's intended. The ball should travel WITH the line and not against it.

Currently I fetch the location of the X and Y of the ball and the X and Y of the
cursor. if one was to mirror the line through the ball, the point I'm looking for  would the the x,y of the mirrored line. (see pic below)

[image: Ball picture]

Any idea on how I might do this?

Comment: Please provide the jsfiddle with your code

Comment: This a math/algorithm question, giving you more code will not give you more context. The function above is all the code relevant to the question.

Comment: It seems you want `ctx.lineTo(ball.position.x + ball.position.x - mouse.x, ball.position.y + ball.position.y - mouse.y);` so that the line goes in the opposite direction, e.g. if the ball position is (3,3) and mouse (2,2) the "mirror" position will be (4, 4).

Comment: @Eogcloud - rather amusing that your diagram used to describe a broken approach is that of a broken image. :laughs:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate the difference between cursor and ball.

```
var difference_x = mouse.x - ball.position.x;
var difference_y = mouse.y - ball.position.y;
```

Then you draw a line between ball position and ball position minus the difference:

```
ctx.lineTo(ball.position.x - difference_x, ball.position.y - difference_y);
```